# Erlang gen_tcp accept vs OS-Thread accept

Tags: sockets, erlang, tcplistener, erlang-otp

I have two models of listening sockets and acceptors in Erlang:

------------FIRST------------

```
-module(listeners).
....

start() ->
{ok, Listen}=gen_tcp:listen(....),
accept(Listen).

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

accept(Listen) ->
{ok, Socket}=gen_tcp:accept(Listen),
spawn(fun() ->handle(Socket) end),
accept(Listen).

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

handle(Socket) ->
....
```

---------SECOND----------

```
-module(listener).
....

start() ->
supervisor:start_link({local,?MODULE},?MODULE, []). 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%

init([]) ->
{ok, Listen}=gen_tcp:listen(....),
spawn(fun() ->free_acceptors(5) end), 
{ok, {{simple_one_for_one, 5,1},[{child,{?MODULE,accept,[Listen]},....}]}.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%

free_acceptors(N) ->
[supervisor:start_child(?MODULE, []) || _ <-lists:seq(1,N)],
ok.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%

accept(Listen) ->
{ok, Socket}=gen_tcp:accept(Listen). 
handle(Socket). 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

handle(Socket) ->
....
```

The first code is simple, the main process creates a listen socket and listen to accept new connections, when a connection came, it accept the connection spawn a new process to handle it and returns to accept other new connections.

The second code is also simple, the main process creates a supervision tree, the supervisor creates a listen socket and start 5 childs (spawning a new process to run `free_acceptors/1` because this function calls the supervisor process and the supervisor is in it's init function and it can't start childs before it's own start so the new process will wait the supervisor until it finishes it's initiation) and give the listen socket as an argument to it's childs, and the five children start listen to accept new coming connections at the SAME time.

So we run the two codes each in a separate machine that have a CPU with a single core and 5 clients try to connect at the same time to the first server and other 5 to the second server: from the first look, i thinked that the second server is faster because all connections will be accepted in parallel and at the same time and in the first code the fivest client will wait the server to accept the precedents four to accept it and so on.
but going deeply at the ERTS, we have a single OS-Thread per core to handle erlang processes and since a Socket is an OS structure then `gen_tcp:listen` will call `OS-Thread:listen` (this is just pseudo code to understand) to create an OS Socket and `gen_tcp:accept` calls `OS-Thread:accept` to accept new connection and this later can accept just one connection at a time and the fivest client still wait the server to accept the fourth precedents, so is there difference between the two codes ? i hope that you understand me.

Even if the code doesn't include sockets the Erlang processes will be always concurrent and not parallel because there is just one core, but the Sheduler will manage tasks between processes very fast and close to parallel run, so the problem is in the use of sockets that use OS calls across the single OS-Thread.

NOTE : Ejabberd use the first implementation and Cowboy use the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At OS level, a listen socket has associated a queue of OS-threads waiting to accept connections, regardless of whether this queue has any OS-thread blocked on it or is empty because it will be handled differently (busy-waiting non-blocking accept, select, epoll...).

The BEAM does not have a single OS-thread even if you run it on a system with a single CPU, it has [different types of OS-threads](https://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#statistics_microstate_accounting)

Regarding your question I suspect that it will be, if anything, better to have multiple acceptor erlang-threads continuously blocking on the `gen_tcp:accept` call because that way the ERTS has knowledge about the erlang code willing to accept more connections (the `handle(Socket)` in your second example should spawn a worker or send the accepted socket to a worker and get back to accept connections) while with the single accept-spawn loop this knowledge is hidden.

I'm not familiar enough with the [code](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/8a50ea621af99fa7e8ccca4db5d771ef6ead4b25/erts/emulator/drivers/common/inet_drv.c#L10280-L10389) to know the nuances, but it seems that the code handles multiple accepts nicely, queueing them internally, so it might be marginally better to have multiple acceptors.
I.e. In the first example with a single request there is a moment where there is nobody `accept`ing connections, while you need a higher number of simultaneous request in the second example for this to happen.

Comment: Thank you José to be here again you helped me a lot and give me an ocean of questions that should be answered before start a project for more efficiency and easy scalability.

Comment: But here you have wrong there is a single Sheduler per single OS-Thread per Core at the BEAM Virtual Machine and you can check this here (https://medium.com/flatiron-labs/elixir-and-the-beam-how-concurrency-really-works-3cc151cddd61)  and i validate these informations from references (you will find one or two original articles from Ericsson Company in references) and you can see all the development of concurrency in ERTS across Erlang/OTP versions.

Comment: I know that the code in the second example is not complete but i did it just for 5 connections to understanding my question. So there is just one OS-Thread that manage all erlang processes and here we can't talk about Blocking and Poll because these terms used when we have multi OS-Thread that listen on one Socket.

Comment: Thank you for the link i have run ```erlang:statistics(microstate_accounting)``` on a server that have 8 cores and 2 Threads per Core and like i expected i had 16 OS-Thread of type Sheduler and many other Threads but these lasts additional Threads do just some helps to the OS for more performance but no one of these Threads is related with our Erlang program and no one of these can interact with Erlang processes and the only that manages the program and do all OS calls is the Sheduler Thread. So for that the other OS-Threads are negligible and should never expect something from these Threads.

Comment: as mentioned in the Ericsson's abstract : you can always modify the default behaviour of the ERTS and add OS-Threads to each core like you want but this has absolutely no advantage over the default single OS-Thread

Comment: By default the number of schedulers is equal to the number of CPUs, true, but there are more types of OS-threads, The one I think that's relevant here is [`poll`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html#+IOt), which stays at 1 by default even with multiple CPUs.

Comment: Thanks can you tell me EXACTLY what is it's job here ? an explained answer without links if you can please like i explain things

Comment: i thing both of us have right, this OS-Thread is introduced since Erlang/OTP 21 and before that it's job was a part of the Sheduler work here's the link (https://blog.erlang.org/IO-Polling/)

Comment: now the missing part is detailed explanation of what happens between Erlang processes and Poll Thread when listening and accepting a socket

Answer (score 0):

iam cumming from lot of search about, so i think that i found the answer for that, but i want just to correct me Mr José if i have wrong in anything :

1-when we run `gen_tcp:listen` the ERTS opens an ERLANG port (a listen socket) to communicate with a linked-in C driver, this driver which runs under a MAIN OS-Thread opens a REAL SOCKET.

2-when we run `gen_tcp:accept` the ERTS use this port to call the driver using a Specified Macro as an argument to the function  `erlang:port_control`, the driver MAIN OS-Thread will spawn an OS-Thread that will run a REAL accept at the opened Socket(Blocking Accept) but this is just my view me too i'm not familiar with the C `Accept` function, anyway this is the Ericsson's Team job.

3-when a client send a request to connect to this Socket, the OS-Thread accept the connection and create a new Socket of communication with this client and the Erlang process creates a new Port and link it to this OS-Thread to be the driver for this specified communication with that client.

4-when the Erlang process send Data via this new port the new driver send this Data via the new Socket, and the same with Receive Data.

5-The MAIN OS-Thread driver will not spawn a new OS-Thread at each Erlang `Accept` and will do a balance between OS-Threads and connections (again this is the Ericsson Design) and these Threads will manage connections with one of the known functions (select, poll, epoll,.....) and generally it's `epoll` for Linux and `Kqueue` for Bsd Systems and each OS-Thread will run this function at dual sides :one side to interact with clients sockets and one side to interact with Erlang ports.

this is the exact work of any driver, it hidden things and let's the Emulator behaves like it does the work directly.

the answer to the first question is that the second code is more efficient and like you have tell me, when there are many Erlang-Acceptors the Driver knows about this and spawns many OS-Acceptors, here there is another problem: how many acceptors i can spawn for a socket ?

the free acceptors design is for accepting connections in PARALLEL and it's clear that one OS-Thread can't accept two connections at the same time so if the number of acceptors is larger than the number of cores for example if we have 8 cores and 10 acceptors and 20 clients came at the same time, we have 8 accepted connections in parallel and next another 8 in parallel and next 4 so this has the same efficiency that we create 8 free acceptors.( i talk about correct version of code when we have always 8 free acceptors and when an acceptor accept a connection it spawns a process to handle this connection and return to accept other connections)

Networking is the most important part in designing fault-tolerant and scalable servers in Erlang/OTP and i want to understand it well before doing anything so Please Mr José if iam wrong in something just tell me Thank you.